# Consolidating Domains from 2 UPN's to 1

Tags: domain-controller, active-directory

We currently have 1 domain (no children) at `corp.domain.com`.  We have an alternate UPN so that users can have their UPN as `username@domain.com` (no `corp`).

Many of our earlier users however have the old style `username@corp.domain.com` UPN.

I can't find any good answers as to the effects of changing the UPN for all these users to remove the `corp` from their UPN's.  I know that because the user SID does not change and the domain is still the same, securities will still be the same, but I don't know what other surprises might be waiting for me.

Comment: As I understand it, there were some gotchas when using Lync with that UPN that you should probably investigate.

Comment: We do use lync, but all e-mail and lync services are hosted by office 365, I will invistegate to make sure that change is not synced using dirsync (no federation just yet).